# Keeping first character in string, in a specific single field

Tags: perl, awk, field

I am trying to remove all but the first character of a specific field in a .tab file.  I want to keep only first character in fields 10 and 11.

Normally the fields have 35 characters in them, so I used:

```
awk '{gsub ("..................................$","",$10;print} file
```

however, there are some fields which have less than 35, and were ignored by this replace function.  I tired using substring, but I cannot figure out how to make it field specific.  I believe there is a way to use perl inside awk so that I can use the function

```
perl -pe 's/(.).*/$1/g'
```

but I am not sure how to do that and use the field as the input value, so the file comes out identical except for the altered field.

is there a way to do the perl equivalent with gsub, or the awk equivalent with perl?

help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i=10;i<=11;i++) { $i = substr( $i, 1, 1) } } { print }' infile
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done. Though `{ print }` can be replaced by `1`. :)

Comment: worked like a charm.  I remotely understand the i definition section, though how it works in a loop for akw I am confused.  Can anyone suggest reading using loops and using substr in awk?

Comment: Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins. Or read any "C" book as loops and substr() are the same in awk and C.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `gensub` function of `gawk`

```
gawk '{ for (i=10;i<=11;i++) { $i = gensub(/(.).*/ , "\\1", G , $i) } }1' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

A shortest `awk` version, I could figure out:

```
awk '($10=substr($10,1,1))&&$11=substr($11,1,1)' infile
```

If the 10th and/or 11th field is not existing then the line is not printed.

Similar version in `perl`

```
perl -ane '$F[9]=~s/(.).*/$1/;$F[10]=~s/(.).*/$1/;print "@F\n"' infile
```

This prints the line even if 10th and/or 11th field is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with perl:

```
perl -pe '$c=0; s/(\S+)/(++$c < 10 || $c > 11) ? $1 : substr($1,0,1)/eg' filename
```